# One to one mapping org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Everything worked fine, until I tried to map relationship between entity classes, UserAccount and Profile. 
UserAccount has a primary key "id", and Profile has a primary key "nickname", which is a foreign key of UserAccount.
 Exception occurs when i try to log in. When using username and password that doesn't exists, this exception doesn't occur.
Irrelevant fields omitted.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="users",  uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint( columnNames=
  {"user_id", "username", "nickname", "email"} ) }     )

  public class UserAccount implements Serializable {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7400604230107519063L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="user_id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=12)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name="username", nullable=false, unique=true, length=25)
  private String username;

  @Column(name="nickname", nullable=false, unique=true, length=25)
  private String nickname;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="userAccount")
  @Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  private Profile profile;





  @Entity
  @Table(name="profiles",  uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint( 
  columnNames={"nickname"} ) }     )
  public class Profile implements Serializable {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6888548766932228312L;

  @Id
  @Column(name="nickname", nullable=false, unique=true, length=25)
  private String nickname;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="nickname")
  private UserAccount userAccount;




  public UserAccount getUserAccount(String username) 
  {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String hql = "from UserAccount U where U.username =:user_username";
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Query<UserAccount> query = 
    session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("user_username",username);
    List<UserAccount> result = (List<UserAccount>)query.list(); //exception 
    return result.get(0);
  }


    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for 
 class com.app.web.social.model.Profile.         Expected: class 
 java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1420)
at com.app.web.social.dao.UserDAOImpl.getUserAccount(UserDAOImpl.java:69)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.getUserAccount(Unknown Source)
at com.app.web.social.service.SocialWebAppUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(SocialWebAppUserDetailsService.java:29)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
... 42 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.app.web.social.model.Profile. Expected: class java.lang.String, got         class java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.checkIdClass(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:166)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1122)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:646)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:165)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1152)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1011)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:384)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without further details, I'm going to presume it is because the @Id column 'nickname' for Profile is an Integer on the database table.

Is the Profile table's id defined as an Integer?

Because 'nickname' is declared as a String in your @Entity code and Hibernate is expecting a String as the Exception states.

Comment: Profile table's id is defined as varchar.